# How can I reuse a Numba device / cuda function on the CPU?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cuda, numba

I have a numba device function that can be executed on a machine wit a CUDA GPU?

```
def kernel_test(window, kernel):
    np_dmisc = cuda.to_device(np.array([window]))
    kernel[80, 64](np_dmisc)
    cuda.synchronize()


@cuda.jit(device=True)
def a_device_function(a, b):
    return 2


kernel_test(1200, a_device_function)
```

I would like to reuse the code of `a_device_function` and call it directly on the CPU, like a normal python function sometimes.

If I attempt to just call it directly, I get this:

```
ValueError: 
Kernel launch configuration was not specified. Use the syntax:

kernel_function[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](arg0, arg1, ..., argn)
```

Is it possible to do this? I am trying to avoid copying the function and having to maintain the code twice.

Comment: You understand how decorators work in python, right?